# Weird margin in Polymer tutorial project - how to remove?

Tags: html, css, web, polymer

I am just testing out the [Polymer tutorial](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-1.html) (please see tutorial page for html/css etc), and I am puzzled by this margin:

[image]

As you can see, to the left of the "ALL"-tab, there is a blue margin. In Firefox and Firebug it looks like this:

[image]

There seems to be two parts on the left (and probably right), where there is some form of buffer. I have been unable to find where that space comes from, and therefore unable to remove it.

I've tried setting padding, margin to zero, and via FireFox removing stuff to get it to disappear, but I have not found it.

Anyone knows?

Comment: Can you post the code in your question and add a jsfiddle with the problem? Its impossible to help without any code.

Answer (score 0):

First padding comes from here (index.html):

```
core-toolbar .toolbar-tools {
    height: 64px;
    padding: 0 8px; /* <--- */
    pointer-events: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

than margin from here:

```
paper-tab .tab-content {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 12px; /* <--- */
    transition: opacity 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1) 0s, color 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1) 0s;
}
```

If you remove margin and padding and additionally set:

```
paper-tabs {
    height: 64px;
}
```

menu items will take full height of blue header area.

Comment: Where do you find these CSS-classes? What file exactly? I dont see it in any index.html, i checked \components\core-toolbar\core-toolbar.html, \components\core-toolbar\index.html, \finished\index.html and \starter\index.html ?

Comment: All of these were inside the file we were looking, inside the html. At the end, is it important? In order to remove them, just override (that was the question). Think it was `step-1/index.html`.